# Apostrophe S Issue While Echoing a Variable

Tags: php

I am working on system and handling sessions using usernames. Usernames like Jack's Peter's are storing properly in Database but when I store it in my sessions variable and echo then it messes up everything.

They are echoed like Jack\'s Peter\'s

Any solution?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- It was a pretty straight forward question that's why I did not post the code. Anyway, I have got the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested please use `stripslashes`.

Returns a string with backslashes stripped off. (\' becomes ' and so on.) Double backslashes (\) are made into a single backslash ().

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
echo stripslashes($str);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php